# Error in Android manifest file. Doesn't seem able to load permissions

Tags: android, xml, xsd

I'm trying to access android's contacts. But when i try to run the code, it says that it requires the Read Contacts permission. well, i already added that and when i try to validate my manifest file it shows some errors. This is my manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="henrique1.birthdaynotifier" >
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name="henrique1.birthdaynotifier.MainActivity" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

and these are the errors i get when trying to validate:

Error:(4, 43) cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'manifest'.

Error:(1, 56) s4s-elt-schema-ns: The namespace of element 'x' must be from the schema namespace, 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema'.

Error:(1, 56) s4s-elt-invalid: Element 'x' is not a valid element in a schema document.

Error:(1, 56) schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'null', because 1) could not find the document; 2) the document could not be read; 3) the root element of the document is not .

I would really appreciate some help here :)

Thanks in advance,
Henrique.

Comment: What Android version are you running? Marshmallow?

Comment: Yeah the latest one right?

Comment: Is that your full manifest file?

Comment: Yes, that is everything.

Comment: @HenriqueSaraiva Yes, if yes you will need to ask runtime permission instead just declaring it in manifest. Will write an answer for it

Comment: @Niko: `uses-permission` is still needed to support the previous versions of android.

Comment: @Melvin yes, I didn't say he need to delete it right? ;)

Comment: But what about the xml manifest errors? Is it not important?

Comment: @Niko: haha yes, but it won't fix the issue he has now, but the one he is going to have after fixing this one (I'm talking about your "Will write an answer for it").

Comment: Your xml manifest looks fine to me, try to clean your project?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are running your app on Marshmallow (API 23) and you will need ask user permission in Runtime instead just declaring it inside the Manifest.

You can use this for asking the permission :

```
    private void askForReadContactsPermission() {
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(KamelioLoginActivity.this,
                Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS)) {
            Snackbar.make(loginMainContainer, "We need your permission to read your contacts information",
                    Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE)
                    .setAction(android.R.string.ok, new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {
                            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MyActivity.this,
                                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS},
                                    PERMISSION_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS);
                        }
                    })
                    .show();
        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MyActivity.this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS},
                    PERMISSION_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS);
        }
    }
```

and Override onRequestPermissionsResult inside your Activity and get the result there

```
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions,
                                           @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        if (requestCode == PERMISSION_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS) {
            if (grantResults.length == 1 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // Permission granted, read the contacts
            } else {
                // Permission not granted, show alert or snack bar
            }
        } else {
            super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Sorry but i can't make it to work. I am really new to android so please have some patience with me. It doesnt recognize many things like the Snackbar (class?). So i am supposed to put this code into the MainActivity java file?